# How to transfer ethereum from one account to another using address and password.?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I want to transfer ether from one account to another using Web3j. I have account address and password.

How to submit transaction?

EDIT 1: 
I'm using this way to send the transaction:

```
HttpService httpService = new HttpService(envConfiguration.getTestnetkeyStorePath());
            Admin admin = Admin.build(httpService);

            PersonalUnlockAccount  credentials1 = admin.personalUnlockAccount(from, existingpassword).send();
            LOGGER.info("credentials  :"+credentials1.accountUnlocked());

            Transaction trx = Transaction.createEtherTransaction(from, nonce, gasprice, gaslimit, to, amount);
            EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction = admin.personalSendTransaction(trx, existingpassword).send();
             transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();
            LOGGER.info("Transaction hash :"+transactionHash);
```

But I'm getting transaction hash as null, Don't know what is going wrong.?
ANy help.?
PS: Thanks in advance.

Comment: the answer to this question is on Google

Comment: @Nulik, I have tried but didn't find any suitable answer. If you have please share the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account address and password alone cannot be used alone. The password you are talking about is used to decrypt the encrypted private key.

There is an [article](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Ether-transfer-from-one-account-to-another-account-using-Web3j-and-Java) which you can use to send ether from one party to another.

The steps followed are as follows:

- Create Web3j object to connect ethereum server.
- Calculate transaction fee which is essential for doing transaction. Transaction fee will be equal to `gas * gas price`, i.e. minimum gas required for transation is 21000.
- Create credentials object.
- Prepare txn by adding the details.

  `var rawTx = {
          nonce: web3.toHex(nonce),
          gasLimit: web3.toHex(41334),
          gasPrice: web3.toHex(10),
          to: addressTo,
          from: addressFrom,
          value: web3.toHex(100)
        }`
- Sign the txn using the private key
- Serialize the txn and convert it to hex
- Send the raw txn.

For more details you can refer to the [documentation](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of web3j.